# A good manual for Firebug

Tags: firefox, documentation, firebug

I can't find a book on how to best use Firebug or at least a sort of .pdf file.

Just small guides.

Does anyone have a link on this.

Answer (score 2):

There is the [GetFirebug wiki](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)